# Prove that there exists $n\ \in \mathbb N$ such that $M^n\subseteq Q \subseteq M$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, $M$ a maximal ideal and $Q$ a $M$-primary ideal ($\sqrt{Q} = M$). Prove that there exists $n\ \in \mathbb N$ such that $M^n\subseteq Q \subseteq M$.

I was trying to prove this using contradiction:

If for all $n\in \mathbb N$ we have that $M^n \not\subseteq Q$, then we can find elements $x_k\in M^k\setminus Q$.

After this, I tried to use the fact that $A$ is Noetherian taking advantage of the fact that any family of ideals will have a maximal element.

I was considering the set $\{ x_kA:k\in \mathbb N \}$ and thus this set has a maximal element $x_hA$. I then tried to relate this to one of the hypotheses but I couldn't do it.

Is this the correct approach? How would you prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a contradiction (this should almost never be the first proof instinct).

$Q \subseteq M$ is trivial. We only need to find $n$ with $M^n \subseteq Q$. Let us prove more generally:

> If $Q,M$ are ideals in a commutative ring with $M \subseteq \sqrt{Q}$ and $M$ is finitely generated, then $M^n \subseteq Q$ for some $n$.

By assumption, $M$ is finitely generated, say $ M= \langle m_1,\dotsc,m_k \rangle$, and there is some (why?) $r \geq 0$ such that $m_1^r,\dotsc,m_k^r \in Q$. By the pigeonhole principle (the details are your exercise) now $M^{rk} \subseteq \langle m_1^r,\dotsc,m_k^r \rangle \subseteq Q$. $~\checkmark$

Comment: why is $M^{rk} \subseteq \langle m_1^r,\dotsc,m_k^r \rangle$ and why is it related to the pigeonhole principle? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Use the definition of the ideal product and think about it a few hours hours. Look at the example $k=3$, $r=2$.

Comment: Thanks. The (obvious) typo is fixed. Please edit the post next time, and notice that comments are not for suggesting (in particular, obvious) corrections: see **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: I don't get it @MartinBrandenburg. Imagine that $M$ is generated by $a$ and $b$. then $M^2$ would be generated by $a^2,ab,b^2$. In the case where we are considering $M^{rk}$ we will have generators that are products of different $m_i$'s right? How is it a subset of $\langle m_1^r,...,m_k^r \rangle$?

Comment: You haven't followed my hint / are ignoring my comments. You are now considering $r=k=2$. So you should compute $M^4$, not $M^2$.